# What exactly is "crippled" about Tinymce4's forced_root_block?

Tags: html, tinymce, contenteditable, tinymce-4

On the official [documentation page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block) of Tinymce, they say

> Note that not using P elements as root block can severly cripple the functionality of the editor

What exactly is crippled in the TinyMCE editor's forced_root_block? I've been using this successfully for a long time in WP environment, and my best guess is that this warning was left from a previous 4.x version that had buggy behavior.

Are there actually any *current* bugs with the forced_root_block behavior? Considering that many systems (Including practically every webmail system) uses `<br>` or `<div>` instead of paragraphs, I'm surprised they still say TinyMCE has such an odd restriction.